# C++ Copy Assignment Operator issues

Tags: c++, c++11

Below is a snippet of my C++  code that deals with Copy assignment operator :

```
StudentRecord & operator=(const StudentRecord & rhs) {
if (this != &rhs ){
    StudentRecord::name = rhs.name;
    StudentRecord:: surname = rhs.surname;
        StudentRecord::studentNumber=rhs.studentNumber;
        StudentRecord::classRecord = rhs.classRecord;
        int newToken= StudentRecord::aquire_token();
        if(StudentRecord::token != -1){
            //Error here
            StudentRecord::release_token( StudentRecord::token );
        }

}


return (*this);
}
```

Below is the declaration of the member function in the .h header file:

```
StudentRecord operator=(const StudentRecord  & rhs);
```

However I get the following error message using Eclipse on Linux:

```
Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:void release_token(int)'
```

Is this something I should be concerned about given that Eclipse in my experience is prone to misbehaving when in use as ide for C++ development. It this is a genuine concern, why is the error occurring and what  step are necessary to fix the error

Please I really need to know.

```
#ifndef  _STUDENT_H
#define  _STUDENT_H
#include <string>
namespace dnkmat001 {
class StudentRecord
{

public:
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    std::string studentNumber;
    std::string classRecord;
    int token;

public:
    StudentRecord(const std::string&  n , const std::string& s , const std::string& x , const std::string& c );
    StudentRecord(void);
    StudentRecord(const StudentRecord & rhs);
    StudentRecord(StudentRecord && rhs );
    StudentRecord operator=(const StudentRecord  & rhs);
    StudentRecord operator=(const StudentRecord  && rhs);
    ~StudentRecord();
    int avg(void);
    static int aquire_token();
    void release_token(int t);
};

  }
 #endif
```

Here is the declaration of release_token(int):

```
void release_token(int t);
```

Comment: How about posting the declaration for StudentRecord::release_token()

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, it is

Comment: The declaration of `void release_token(int)` is probably wrong. Please post it.

Comment: @hivert Add the declaration

Comment: So why are you calling it with a `StudentRecord::token` ?

Comment: Is there a reason *besides* obscurity you're cluttering all this member function code with repetitious `StudentRecord::` resolutions that aren't needed?

Comment: @WhozCraig what do I do instead?

Comment: You're in a member function. Just use the names of the members. `name = rhs.name;` etc...

Comment: @WhozCraig I then get  name can not be resolved errors.

Comment: In the assignment operators signature (`StudentRecord::StudentRecord & operator=(const StudentRecord & rhs)`), what is the difference between `StudentRecord` and `StudentRecord::StudentRecord`? This looks strange to me, I'd rather expect the signature to be something like: `StudentRecord & StudentRecord::operator=(const StudentRecord & rhs)`

Comment: post the full class definition of `StudentRecord` then.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich added class declareration in header file

Comment: I'm missing something?

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of the assignment operator in the class definition is:

```
StudentRecord operator=(const StudentRecord  & rhs);
```

Then you write

```
StudentRecord & operator=(const StudentRecord & rhs) {
 //...
}
```

But that is not a definition of the function you declared in the class. It's rather a free function which also makes immediately clear why the compiler complains if you don't qualify each variable with its class name. You need to tell the compiler that you're defining a function that was previously declared in the class StudentRecord by qualifying it explicitly. Also note that your function is declared to return `StudentRecord`, but it should return `StudentRecord &`.

Change the signature of your function definition as follows:

```
StudentRecord & StudentRecord::operator=(const StudentRecord & rhs) {
 //...
}
```

Also remove all `StudentRecord::` qualifiers inside the function body for the sake of readability.

Comment: Always something simple. facepalm